# How to insert and calculate values via trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 2 tables in my mssql Db.

```
[dbo].[Jobs]([StartDate],[FinishDate],[Description],[UserId])

[dbo].[Penalties]([Cost],[Description],[UserId])

And following trigger 
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerPenalty
ON dbo.Jobs AFTER INSERT
AS
INSERT dbo.Penalties(Cost, Description, UserId)
SELECT Cost, Description, UserId
FROM dbo.Jobs
```

But in my Cost value I need to insert precalculated value which depends on date: cost = (get minutes from start date if it greater than 10:00 AM)*100. And also I need that my trigger must be started only if start date time is greater than 10:00 AM. Can anybody help me? I'm newbie in triggers.

Comment: " I'm newbie in triggers." - then please read the online doco

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use "instead of trigger" for insert, it will help in solving your query. The below is not the running code but it will give you fair idea of triggers.

```
enter code here

CREATE TRIGGER TriggerPenalty
  ON dbo.Jobs INSTEAD OF Insert
  AS

  declare @cost int, @Description varchar(255), @userid int

  select @cost=i.cost from inserted 
  select @Description=i.Description from inserted 
  select @Userid=i.Userid from inserted 

  if Getdate()>'Startdate'
  begin
     Process the logic

  end
```